# Unable to add the algebra equation with the calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently having a problem with the following equation

$$\frac{2x - 5}{2y^2 - 50} +\frac{4}{3y^2 - 13y - 10}$$

However, I cannot add the equation with a calculator. What is the answer?
Some examples or tips will be helpful! I would like to hear from you!

PS. If possible some step to step for the following equation would be great!

Comment: The formula in the image is not an equation. Do we have to solve for $x,y$ when that term equals to zero ?

Comment: Based on the denominator values are you trying to factor stuff out?

Comment: Or do you just want to write it as a single fraction ?

Comment: single fraction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments the given expression is not an equation, because we don't have an equality that can be verified (or not) by some value of $x$ and/or $y$.

You can write the expression in a simpler form noting that the denomiators can be factorized as:
$$
2y^2-50=2(y^2-25)=2(y-5)(y+5)
$$
$$
3y^2-13y-10=3y^2+2y-15y-10=y(3y+2)-5(3y+2)=(3y+2)(y-5)
$$

and using the usual rule for the addition of fractions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the two fractions, compute the least common multiple of $2(y^2-20)$ and $3y^2-13y-10=(y-5)(3y-2)$:
$$\frac{2x-5}{2(y^2-25)}+\frac4{(y-5)(3y-2)}=\frac{(2x-5)(3y-2)+8(y+5)}{2(y^2-25)(3y-2)}=\frac{6xy-4x-9y+50}{2(y^2-25)(3y-2)}.$$